# Высоконагруженные проекты на c#

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Подскажите примеры высоконагружённых пректов на c#. Плюсом будет, если расскажете об архитектуре. Высоконагружённые проекты - это проекты, которые пользуются популярностью больше 100000 клиентов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За примером далеко ходить не надо -- [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com). Гугл выдает достаточно статей по запросам "[stackoverflow architecture](https://www.google.ru/search?q=stackoverflow+architecture)".

Обзорные статьи:

http://www.insight-it.ru/masshtabiruemost/arkhitektura-stack-overflow/ (старая)
http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html (новая)

Видео:

http://www.dev-metal.com/architecture-stackoverflow/

Comment: И только? Про MSDN забыли?